# cordova open local file on windows 8.1 platform

Tags: cordova, windows-8.1, window.open, local-files

I am working with cordova based hybrid application targeted to Windows 8.1 platform. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 IDE for debugging and testing. I am trying to open an image saved locally on device say "C:\image.jpg"

I tried multiple options like:

Use of window.open with file protocol as window.open("file:///C:/image.jpg");

Also tried fileopener2 plugin as

cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                'C://image.jpg', 
                'application/jpg', 
                { 
                    error : function(e) { 
                        console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                    },
                    success : function () {
                        console.log('file opened successfully');
                    }
                }
            );

But none of them works.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chirag.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not very well documented, cordova childBrowser doesn't support opening non-HTML files. This is due to the underlying child Browser implementation provided by Microsoft.

Either let the user pick an external app to open the file as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32935380/1479685)

```
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
                var localFolder = applicationData.localFolder;
                console.log(localFolder);

                var imageFile = "image.png";

                // Get the image file from the package's image directory
                localFolder.getFileAsync(imageFile).then(
                  function (file) {
                      console.log("1");
                      // Set the show picker option
                      var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
                      options.displayApplicationPicker = true;

                      // Launch the retrieved file using the selected app
                      Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).then(
                        function (success) {
                            if (success) {
                                // File launched
                                console.log("2");
                            } else {
                                // File launch failed
                                console.log("3");
                            }
                        });
                  });
```

or take a look at the [Windows.Data.Pdf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.pdf.aspx) namespace if you'd like to try rolling your own in-app solution.