# window.open to open local image,pdf on windows platform using InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, windows-8.1, inappbrowser, local-files

I am working on cordova based hybrid application targeted to Windows 8.1 platform with InAppBrowser plugin added. I have used following code to open local image/pdf file:

**window.open("Screenshot.png", "_blank", "location=no");**

But it does nothing...no exception and no image.

I am able to use the same code to open text file. But the same code does not work with image/pdf/word/excel documents.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chirag.

**Update:** I found solution. Following is the sample code:

```
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
                var localFolder = applicationData.localFolder;
                console.log(localFolder);

                var imageFile = "image.png";

                // Get the image file from the package's image directory
                localFolder.getFileAsync(imageFile).then(
                  function (file) {
                      console.log("1");
                      // Set the show picker option
                      var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
                      options.displayApplicationPicker = true;

                      // Launch the retrieved file using the selected app
                      Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).then(
                        function (success) {
                            if (success) {
                                // File launched
                                console.log("2");
                            } else {
                                // File launch failed
                                console.log("3");
                            }
                        });
                  });
```

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks.